# How to concatenate a part of filename in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to concatenate a part of filename in SQL.

```
 BULK INSERT #NewSegments    
 FROM 'E:\scratch\AT.txt'

 WITH (
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
       )
```

I want to replace AT with a parameter `@CountryCode`.

Below SQL is not working.

```
 BULK INSERT #NewSegments
 FROM 'E:\scratch\' + @CountryCode + '.txt'

 WITH (
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
       )
```

Answer (score 3):

you might require to go for dynamic sql as below:

```
Declare @Query Nvarchar(max)

Set @Query = 'BULK INSERT #NewSegments FROM ''E:\scratch\'+@CountryCode+'.txt'''
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' ) '

exec sp_executeSql @Query
```